# MIDI file has a largest tick of 11222570, it is likely corrupt: How to solve?

Tags: midi

I am using the `pretty-midi` library to load MIDI files for machine learning. However, I am encountering the error message `ValueError: MIDI file has a largest tick of 11222570, it is likely corrupt` when attempting to load some of the files with `pm = pretty_midi.PrettyMIDI(midi_file)`. I am able to play these supposedly corrupt files normally using VLC, so I think they are actually valid.

Is there a way to resolve this error and successfully load these MIDI files using `pretty-midi`?

Comment: This may be a bug, you could try opening an issue at the repository https://github.com/craffel/pretty-midi/issues. Make sure to make one of the problematic midi files available somewhere so the bug can be reproduced and possible solutions tested.

Comment: I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/craffel/pretty-midi/issues/228

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the `pretty-midi` project this is indeed considered a bug in the file: https://github.com/craffel/pretty-midi/issues/112

A workaround is described.